# Convert query to HQL

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hql

I am new to HQL ,i neeed to make the following MSSQLServer query which gets sales per month and year be executed in all database,

```
select count(sales) as monthsales from salesdairy where propertytype in ('item1') and MONTH(time) = MONTH(getdate())
select count(sales) as yearsales from salesdairy where propertytype in ('item1') and YEAR(time) = YEAR(getdate())
```

I get strucked with the function  `MONTH(time) = MONTH(getdate()),YEAR(time) = YEAR(getdate())` is there any equivalent in HQL.
I would appreciate it if anyone could give me an HQL equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in HQL instead of tables you have entities (class object).
I suppose your table salesdiary becomes SalesDiary entity.

First query:

```
select count(S.id)
from SalesDiary S
where S.propertytype in ('item1')
and MONTH(S.time) = MONTH(current_date)
```

Second query:

```
select count(S.id)
from SalesDiary S
where S.propertytype in ('item1')
and YEAR(S.time) = YEAR(current_date())
```

The function MONTH gets the month number of input date, YEAR function gets the year number of input date.

current_date() is equivalent of SQL Server GETDATE().

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**
Very strange, Hibernate must convert with the correct function of underline DBMS.

If you can use parameter try this:

```
select count(S.id)
from SalesDiary S
where S.propertytype in ('item1')
and YEAR(S.time) = YEAR(:currDate)
```

When you get your HQL query to object Query, you0ll replaced your currDate parameter with setDate function in this way:

```
String hql = 
  "select count(S.id)
  from SalesDiary S
  where S.propertytype in ('item1')
  and YEAR(S.time) = YEAR(:currDate)";

Query q = session.createQuery(hql);

q.setDate("currDate", new GregorianCalendar().getTime());
q.list();
```

I hope now it's OK ;)

Comment: no luck, getting 16774 [http-9090-3] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'current_date'.,com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'current_date'.

Comment: @user2779544, please turn on hibernate logging, so we can see generated sql